# What is the number of degrees needed for polynomial curve fitting?

Tags: curve-fitting, polynomials

Assume we have `m` data points.

1. What is the number of degrees needed for polynomial curve fitting if we wish to make the adjusted `R^2` value to be 1? (Theoretically, it will be 1, but realistically it's nearly 1 due to round off errors).
2. What is the reason for the chosen number?

8 points `(2 0 0 3 8 5 3 3 )` example shown below, but you have to answer with `m` data points. If you use 8 data points your score will be reduced.

[image: example]

Comment: m-1. One point determines a constant (degree 0), 2 points determine a line, 3 a degree 2, 4 for degree 3, and so on.

Comment: It depends entirely on your dataset

Answer (score 0):

A polynomial of degree `m-1` will exactly fit (`R^2 = 1`) `m` data points with different x values.

A `m-1` degree polynomial has `m` degrees of freedom `a_i`:

y(x) = a_1 + a_2 x^1 + a_3 x^2 + ... + a_m x^(m-1)

The `m` degrees of freedom of a `m-1` degree polynomial allow it to uniquely fit to `m` data points.